# How to output mustache templates in a twig template?

Tags: symfony, mustache

I need to add mustache templates to a Twig template using symfony2.

Someone has created a 'verbatim' template tag for django and I'm looking for a corresponding one for twig that will prevent it from parsing the mustache elements.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [verbatim tag](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html).

### UPDATE for AlainTiemblo :

But what if you need to write `{% endverbatim %}` verbatim ?
You must then resort to the [least elegant method](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#escaping) (you can't use verbatim anymore)

```
{{'twig code here{% endverbatim %}twig code there' }}
```

If the twig code is big, do this:

```
{% verbatim %}
    twig code here
{% endverbatim %}
{{ '{% endverbatim %}' }}
{% verbatim %}
    twig code there
{% endverbatim %}
```

Comment: One question remains: how to write `{% endverbatim %}` mmhh? :p

Comment: @greg0ire: `{% verbatim %}` allows you to write non-interpreted twig code, and to close it as all tags, you should write `{% endverbatim %}`... so, how to write a raw `{% endverbatim %}` then?

Comment: @AlainTiemblo: oh now I get it... incoming update in my answer, please stand by.

Comment: Lol, thanks, I knew the answer but just wanted to put some salt in here. Anyway, +1 for your sportsmanship.

Answer (score 0):

You can now set directly new tags with Mustache using

```
Mustache.tags = ["[[","]]"];
```

for example.