# Mustache .js show in html template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mustache

I tried to use mustache.js on my web-app. So I charged the mustache.js and in my script I do :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var person = {
            firstName: "Christophe",
            lastName: "Coenraets",
            blogURL: "http://coenraets.org"
        };
        var template = "<h1>{{ firstName }} {{ lastName }}</h1>Blog: {{ blogURL }}";
        var html = Mustache.to_html(template, person);
        console.log(html);
        $('#userListWrapper').html(html);
    });
</script>
```

The problem is that in my `console.log(html)` I get : `<h1> </h1>Blog:`, so the mustache is not interpreted. Can you help me please ? I don't understand where is the problem. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working, you just need to make sure that the libraries are included.

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/2.2.0/mustache.js"></script>
</head>
<p id="userListWrapper"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var person = {
            firstName: "Christophe",
            lastName: "Coenraets",
            blogURL: "http://coenraets.org"
        };
        var template = "<h1>{{ firstName }} {{ lastName }}</h1>Blog: {{ blogURL }}";
        var html = Mustache.to_html(template, person);
        console.log(html);
        $('#userListWrapper').html(html);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I use twig maybe that is problem, not ?

Comment: Well you are using the Mustache object from whats in your original question, if there is no link to this library this is a problem. You can check here also - > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862521/how-to-output-mustache-templates-in-a-twig-template